# Caliburn.Micro EventAggregator with multiple instances

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I have two a Caliburn.Micro ViewModels communicating each other by EventAggregator:

```cs
public class LeftViewModel
{
    // ...
    public void DoInRight()
    {
        messanger.PublishOnUIThread(new DoInRightMessage());
    }
}

public class RightViewModel : IHandle<DoInRightMessage>
{
    public void Handle(DoInRightMessage e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It has worked fine until I had just one instance of `LeftViewModel` and `RighViewModel` on the screen. But now I would like to allow arbitrary number of instances of both of them - always in couples. So `LeftViewModel.DoInRight()` should send the message only in one  `RighViewModel` (the one in the couple), not all `RighViewModel` instances.

**Update 8.7.2015**:
How to solve such pair messaging:

- Some kind of message channels/groups by adding a parameter `target` or `id` to the messages (thanks `@jophy job` for point me to the idea).
- Have multiple EventAggregators.
- Abandon the EventAggregator and call methods directly.
- Or any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using some sort of ID for every View.

there is a similar question  [Caliburn.Micro and event aggregator -unwanted call handle method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530335/caliburn-micro-and-event-aggregator-unwanted-call-handle-method)

Comment: So to make some kind of message channels. Thx for the idea. I'll wait for more responses.